# Joomla MEMORY tables cause an error in creating/editing articles

Tags: database, joomla-4.x

I am encountering an error with Joomla 4 that has never occurred to me in previous installations. When I try to create/edit an article, a category or to index contents in smart search, I get the following error:

*The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin*

I discovered what seems to be the cause: the tables "finder_tokens" and "finder_tokens_aggregate" which are of type MEMORY. When I edit them in innoDB the problem is momentarily solved. But after inserting a new article (for example) these tables are reset to MEMORY and the problem returns.

So changing the engine is certainly not the solution to the problem. Do you have any ideas on how I could solve the problem or what could be the cause? I have never had this kind of problem (on other machines) with previous Joomla installations.

Comment: Is the J$ implementation running on the same environment as your working J3 environment? A search on that message comes up with a few hits on the use of Strict Mode being used on the database and I fixed an issue for a client a little while back where they moved to Maria 10.x and Strict Mode is now the default.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a MySQL error - possibly caused by the fact that the DB user accessing the database doesn't have full privileges over that database. If you are using cPanel, you just "grant" all privileges for the user to the Joomla database. I know that this answer is over a year late but hopefully this will help someone.